# Add dns entry to kubernetes cluster

Tags: dns, kubernetes

I have a vm running jenkins that I would like to reach from my kubernetes cluster. I can reach it on its ip address but need to reach via a domain name as it has a https cert attached. I could use hostaliases but the deployments get created on the fly.

I am using kube-dns. The cluster is gke.

I also tried adding the entry in google cloud dns.

Comment: I was able to solve this by creating an external dns server, then adding that dns server to my kube-dns deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating an external dns server, then adding that dns server to my kube-dns deployment.
`k edit deploy kube-dns -n kube-system`

Just above the line that says dnsPolicy I added my dns server

`dnsConfig:

  nameservers:

  - 10.1.0.28                                                                                                                                                                                                                       dnsPolicy: Default`